# Unable to import entire CSV file into SQL Server

Tags: csv, import, sql-server-2012

I have a CSV file that I exported myself out of SFDC. It has about 60k records.  3 columns are numbers, 1 is a date, & the other dozen or so are Text.

In SSMS or SSIS, when I attempt to import the file to a table - the importer errors out on the same row of data each time "15421" with the error message:

> The data conversion for column XXXX returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page."

The error is pointing to one of the Text columns. When I look at the data in the table to see what imported, the data ends exactly that that row and column - the column is empty. The contents of the column is 2 characters.

My first attempt was to use `DT_STR (255)`, resulting in the error. If I switch to as `DT_WSTR (1024)` or even `DT_NTEXT` - the job runs and reports success, but it ends exactly that row and doesn't import the rest of the 45k records - as if something in that row (and in that column?) is indicating the file is finished at that point.

I looked at that file with Notepad ++ and Sublime Text Gremlins, and Sublime Text Hex editor - I can't see anything abnormal in the data or the text qualifying quotation marks, or the comma delimiters...  Thoughts?  TIA!

Comment: Probably a NUL character. Or maybe the text is too long for the column?

Comment: Thanks @charlieface - Not too long, I did check that and even tried both unicode and non-unicode text stream types.  I've just googled "NUL" characters - it looks like I would need to look at the text in something like Notepad ++...  Did do that, can't see anything abnormal.  Also looked at the lines in hex editor - and that looks fine too.